How to phrase CV when my college didn’t award magna cum laude (in general) while others do?
My professional college within the university only honors the top 10%. Being in the top veterinary medical school in the nation, we are all top performers and even many 4.0 academic records didn’t receive summa cum laude. The university itself acknowledges the top three Latin honors. The other professional colleges within the university also acknowledge them. Mine did years prior but has since stopped.
My question: how do I acknowledge my 3.8 GPA on a CV? I feel like all my hard work isn’t even acknowledged now. Or does it even matter? I’m interviewing for positions where colleagues do have their magna cum laude on their CV and also on their online bio. So my lack of mentioning leads one to believe they graduated with a higher GPA than I did. I don’t want to be petty, but how do I correctly acknowledge my GPA when my professional college did not?

Pretty much nobody cares about honors besides your parents.

@jon yes, they absolutely do in academia positions.

I'd have to concur with @JonCuster on this: at least in math, in the U.S., both for admission to our grad program, and for postdoc applicants, I've never paid attention to any "honors", and I've never heard anyone mention it.

If you’re really concerned, you could just write “3.XX GPA, top X% in class”.

@Happyscholar - no, even for academic positions people don't care because of the differences across schools in awarding honors. Further, hiring folks know that almost anything else in your application materials is more important than whether you got some honor or not.

@Happyscholar It may help to put your general location in the question. Different areas of the world have different expectations with respect to honors. (e.g. From what little I understand, Germany makes a bigger deal of them than the U.S. - which, as Paul Garrett mentions, generally doesn't care about them one bit. Though, IIRC, that's in part because there's a semi-standardized criteria for such titles in Germany.)

Admissions to vet schools are among the most selective in the world.  Everyone in your field who may hire you know this, so there's really no need to highlight your prowess toward getting high grades.  The second you entered a postgraduate program, your grades are a whole lot less important than they once were, and your accolades will come from other endeavors like your research and practice skills.

You can list your GPA in your CV if you like, but make sure that the university agrees with your calculation. And, don't assign it any descriptive title like Magna Cum Laude that your university doesn't, itself, award. Otherwise it is a form of fraud. And definitions of the Latin awards differ among those who use it.
For graduate admissions (and maybe employment), your transcripts will generally be required and they speak for themselves. You don't need more and claiming more would be a mistake.

@buffy- competitive research and specialty internships only require transcripts upon acceptance or my professional license. The screening is the application process. And my competitors are putting their grade accomplishments because their schools do allow for the Latin honors. As does my university in every professional college except mine. So I was trying to figure a way to be competitive in the screening process. I’m not  putting magnum cum loude on my cv. I was asking how do I acknowledge my 3.89 gpa on a cv or if I should even bother. Thank you for your input I appreciate it
